# How can I use 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num' to order by the numerical value even if the value starts with a word?

Tags: post-meta, order, meta-value

I'm using `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'` to order some boats I have as a custom post type, the meta values ordered by, are boat models, which are normally just numbers but if you look at this page: `http://boats-barcos.com/brands/ferretti/` you will see the ALTURA 840 is listed last when it should be between the 800 and 870. This is obviously because the value starts with a word. How can I get the `orderby` query to only order by the numerical value and ignore the word?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [50+ similar questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql%20remove%20non-numeric) you'll see that you can only do so with considerable difficulty, and you won't have a very efficient query once you get it working. MySQL just isn't built to sort that way, and honestly the sort pattern you want is really very peculiar anyway. It isn't a normal sort by any standard.

And that is pure SQL. `WP_Query` is capable of much less finesse-- without the application of filters anyway.

Your best approach is going to be to normalize your data on insert, saving the numeric portion to one key and the rest elsewhere. Or force the number to the front followed by some marker like a comma that will let you juggle it back to the end on display.

Comment: Perfect solution in my opinion. `model_number` and `series` could be the two fields, display them together, but sort on `model_number`. Obviously the variables could be different names.